# Fastest implementation of priority_queue in C++?

Tags: library, c++, data-structure, performance

I stumbled upon custom implementations of hash tables, which are faster than `std::unordered_map` for say, `int` type. (For example `ska::flat_hash_map`)

For my use case, I don't need to optimize memory, the only parameter I want to be optimized is the speed. I want the execution speed to be as fast as possible. The primary operations I am concerned about are push and pop.

What are the fastest state-of-the-art implementations focusing on speed for `priority_queue`? (Note: I am not interested in concurrency, I am running a single-threaded program.)